# Segmentation Fault in VSCode, but works fine on REPL ( C )

Tags: c, reverse

Following is the code of a function to reverse a queue using a stack. Don't know where I am going wrong:

```
void reverse(Queue *q)
{
    int temp1, temp2;
    Stack *s1 = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    removeAllItems(&(s1->ll));
    while(((q->ll).size)!=0)
    {
        temp1 =  (((q->ll).head)->item);
        push(s1,temp1);
        dequeue(q);
    }
    while(((s1->ll).size)!=0)
    {
        temp2 = (((s1->ll).head)->item);
        enqueue(q, temp2 );
        pop(s1);
    }
}
```

Comment: provide some [mre] in your question. Use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` to compile your C code, then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand its behavior. Take inspiration from the source code of existing open source software, like [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)

Comment: Probably because you call `removeAllItems` on an uninitialized pointer. Show `removeAllItems`, the problem ist most likely _there_. Read this: [ask] and then [edit] and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

```
Stack *s1 = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
```

is allocating some *uninitialized* memory. In some cases `malloc` would fail and return `NULL`. In other cases it will reuse some previously `free`-d zone.

You probably want after that `malloc`

```
if (s1 == NULL) { perror("malloc Stack"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
memset (s1, 0, sizeof(Stack));
```

to check against failure of `malloc` and clear properly the memory zone.

```
removeAllItems(&(s1->ll));
```

is accessing some uninitialized field, which could contain garbage data.

Read *Modern C* and the documentation of your C compiler. If you use [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Then use a debugger like [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).

Consider using tools like the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), or [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/), or write your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html), or use [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/).